# Windows 8.1 - black and white after MS logo on bootcamp

Tags: windows, boot, boot-camp

Late 2013 macbook pro with retina display.  The laptop display turns black and white when the logon screen appears.  The screen is color when the MS logo and loading icon is spinning and when the full screen image comes up it is then in black and white.

Some notes:
* Worked fine for last two months
* No new software or updates recently
* Stays color if I load in Safe mode
* Booting into OSX is color
* External displays are color
* Disabling all services and startup programs still gives black and white

Any ideas on what I might disable or what went wrong?

Comment: You sure you didn't enable a theme thats simply black and white have you tried opening a document and change the don't color within it?

Comment: Have you checked the color depth and other color settings in the Control Panel?

Comment: OK, so this is odd.  I thought about the theme but I assumed that since I had a second monitor installed and it was OK that the theme was not it (I thought it would effect both screens).  In the process of re-verifying that idea I set the displays to 'duplicate' rather than extend and it went back to color.  I then reset it to extend and it stayed color so it seems to be fixed.  I'm not sure what happened there.